# Rack-based app and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, database, activerecord, rack

I couldn't find the answer on the web, so here I am ! If you use the activerecord gem in a rack-based app (Sinatra, Merb, Camping …), will you automatically have access to the rake command, like rake db:migrate ? Or do you have to do something more ?

I found about the sinatra-activerecord gem, that give access to that command, but what about the other frameworks ?

Answer (score 2):

`rack` and `rake` are really different gems, however, a lot of developers automate certain tasks in `rack` based apps using `rake`. That is, someone usually has to write the task to get `db:migrate` to work.

Here's what `db:migrate` is really made up of:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'active_record'
require 'logger'

namespace :db do
  desc "Migrate the database through scripts in db/migrate. Target specific version with VERSION=x"
  task :migrate => :environment do
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('db/migrate', ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil )
  end

  task :environment do
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    require_relative './config/db'
  end
end
```

source: https://gist.github.com/2624944

Comment: Yes, yes, I know that the two are different. But I wanna know if you can use directly rake db:migrate in a rack-based app if you install the activerecord gem. But this code may serve, thank you !